# Why setValue() method of MutableLiveData is called from Main Thread only

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have seen at many places that setValue() should be called from MainThread but never got an explanation why?
Can anyone explain the reason under the hood?

Comment: `setValue()` is normally used to trigger an update to the contents of your Activity/Fragment, which would need to be done on the UI thread anyway.